# Show that $T : [0,\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}] \to [0,\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}] $ is mixing.

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems

Is this shuffling map on the unit interval [mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)) ?

$$ f(x)  = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
x + (\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}) & \text{ if } & 0 < x < \sqrt{3} \\ 
x + (\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{3}) & \text{ if } & \sqrt{3} < x < \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \\ 
x - (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}) & \text{ if } & \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} < x < \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}\\ 
\end{array} \right. $$

Here $f : [0, \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}] \to [0, \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}] $ yet we could rescale so to be map $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$.

- this is a 1-1 map
- this exchanges the permutations in the interval $\pi = (3,2,1)$.
- it's called an [interval exchange map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_exchange_transformation).

Such a map is very likely to be **ergodic** and **weak-mixing**. Let's review those definitions.

- for every measurable set $A \in \mathcal{B}$ we have $T^{-1}(A) \subset A$ implies either $\mu(A) = 0$ or $\mu(A) = 1$.
- **strong mixing** $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A \cap T^{-n}B) = \mu(A) \cdot \mu(B)  $ so the two sets $A$ and $B$ are eventually "independent".
- **weak-mixing** $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \left| \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(A \cap T^{-k}B) - \mu(A)\mu(B) \right|= 0 $ so the "average" over all the over lap with the pre-images should be independent.

Maybe one could show that the *invariant measure* of the interval exchange map, is just Lebesgue measure (which served as a replacement for the Riemann integration).  We are guessing as much.

Then one could ask what the strong mixing and weak-mixing statements should represent here.  What **number theory** problem could be represented there?

---

Here is the image after $n = 10^5$ iterations.  So we have $\big\{ (x, T^n (x)) :  x = \frac{m}{10^5} \text{ and }0 < m < 10^5 \big\}$.

[image]

This looks like it might be mixing.  Here is after a million ($n = 10^6$) iteratios.

[image]

There's no formula for the quantative mixing of exchange maps.

Comment: I have no experience nor intuition about this concept. Somehow I got the impression that the plots should become more "space filling". Say if $\Delta$ is a short interval, I expected its (inverse) images to be all over the place. May be my brain is miscalibrated here.

Comment: the rate of mixing, i have to refer to the Chemistry department for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_ratio

Answer (score 1):

Your map is a finite interval exchange transformation (commonly called an IET).  It preserves Lebesgue measure, since the slope on each interval is 1, and it is a bijection a.e.  It was proven here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760655 that every finite interval exchange transformation is not strong mixing.